# pandas groupby a column, then get average number of days from a date column for each group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a pandas datafame like this:

```
    customer_id    transaction_date   ......................
 0    12341          2011-05-06
 1    12341          2011-06-22
 2    12341          2011-05-09
 3    12342          2011-06-16
 4    12342          2011-07-26
 5    12342          2011-03-06
 6    12343          2011-05-16
 7    12343          2011-04-25
 8    12342          2011-07-12
 9    12343          2011-05-09
 10   12343          2011-04-12
 11   12342          2011-07-03
```

I am trying to calculate the average interval a customer make transactions. In other words, every what number of days, does each customer make a transaction.

Here's what I have tried:

```
dummy_data.groupby(by=['customer_id'])['transaction_date'].transform('mean')
```

I get:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

How do I do this?

EDIT 1:

Expected output:

```
customer_id   avg_days
  12341         24
  12342         ..
  12343         ..
```

Explanation:
for customer with id "12341", date of first transaction is may-6, next may-9, next june 22. So, difference of days between first two transactions is 3 days, and between next transaction, 45 days. So, mean for 3 and 45 is (45+3/2 = 48/2 = 24). I would then need to do this for all customers in the dataframe.

Comment: that's a string not an integer column. you are taking mean on dates that's why getting this error

Comment: it is in proper format: `datetime64[ns]`and yes, it is not a numeric column. so, how do i calculate average number of days without error?

Comment: Can you atleast give us the expected output? I didn't get what do you mean by average date?

Comment: I have added the expected output.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert `transaction_date` column to pandas `datetime` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
In [2947]: df.transaction_date = pd.to_datetime(df.transaction_date)
```

Now, add a new column in `df` with days difference between two transcations using [`Groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and find average using [`Groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
In [2976]: df['days'] = (df.sort_values('transaction_date').groupby('customer_id').transaction_date.shift() - df.transaction_date).dt.days.abs()

In [2985]: x = df.groupby('customer_id', as_index=False)['days'].mean().round()

In [2986]: x
Out[2986]: 
   customer_id  days
0        12341  24.0
1        12342  36.0
2        12343  11.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering your df:

```
def AVG_diff(x):
    # Integer number of Days
    return x.diff().mean()

df = df.sort_values(['customer_id', 'transaction_date'], ascending=[True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
df['transaction_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['transaction_date'])
df.groupby('customer_id')['transaction_date'].apply(lambda x: AVG_diff(x)).reset_index()
```

---

**Result:**

```
   customer_id transaction_date
0        12341 23 days 12:00:00
1        12342 35 days 12:00:00
2        12343 11 days 08:00:00
```

**Update:**

```
x = df.groupby('customer_id')['transaction_date']
aggs = df.assign(avg_num=x.diff().dt.days) \
               .groupby(['customer_id'], as_index=False)['avg_num'].mean().round()
```

---

**aggs:**

```
   customer_id  avg_num
0        12341     24.0
1        12342     36.0
2        12343     11.0
```

Comment: `apply` basically is loops under the hood. So it's slow. Please check my solution.

Comment: Yes apply is slower but if the size of the data is not too large then it's okay to use it.

Comment: I never said, its not okay to use `apply`. Just pointed this out that `apply` will affect the performance when the size grows. People here want to give the best answer they can. I am trying to do the same.